# add inline style with background image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I'm trying to add an img background to some react component like this

```
  var imageStyle = {
  color: '#fff',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + { this.props.top_room.avatar } + ')',
  background: 'bottom right 15% no-repeat #46B6AC;'
};

var TopRoom = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp demo-card-square">
        <div className="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand" style={imageStyle}>
```

but it is not working. How can I add this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use curly braces in such case.

Something like this should work

```
var imageStyle = {
  color: '#fff',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.props.top_room.avatar + ')',
  background: 'bottom right 15% no-repeat #46B6AC;'
};
```

Comment: Now I'm seeing `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.top_room')` seems like that at this point, the props is empty

Comment: nevermind, added before the `return` inside the component did the trick. Thanks!